# CORS in ionic app and django

Tags: cordova, cors, ionic-framework, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I am building an ionic app with django-rest api ,used cors header plugin in django to allow cross origin request

i set configuration

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

to allow all the urls for testing as in the white list

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
        'google.com',
)
```

we can only give url and app runs on "file://location" .

app is running fine when i test it on browser but does'nt fetch data when i test it on emulator

Can anyone please tell how to set domain for mobile app in CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST=() and configuration in ionic app so that it can fetch data from django rest apis ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi Ajeet.  I believe that browsers have additional security constraints on `file://*` destinations. That might be causing your issue. I recommend serving up the file with python by going to the file's directory and doing  `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`.  Then you Will be able to go to `http://localhost:8080/` and see your dev files.

Comment: Or just use ionic's own server: `ionic serve` ;-)

Comment: @QueryLars  my app is already running on browser ...... how does `ionic serve`  going to help when i am testing it as a **native app** on android emulator ?

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Could be a problem related to cordova whitelist plugin. See [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide) Maybe this helps you.

Comment: I already have whitelist plugin installed and by default  config.xml have  `<access origin="*" />` that means it should allow access to all urls . Is'nt that right ?